# How to run (.py) Python files locally in web browser?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to run (.py) Python files locally on a web browser without running a web server? Not using an external service also. So if the internet isn't available the file will still run in the browser. I want to run this code on my pc in Chrome or IE. Thank you.

```
def concept(phrase):

# split var(phrase) at spaces and assign to var(words)
words = phrase.split()

# use this to list python file titles and links to open them
files    = {1:"file0001.txt",
            2:"file0002.txt",
            3:"file0003.txt",
            4:"file0004.txt",
            5:"file0005.txt",
            6:"file0006.txt",
            7:"file0007.txt",    
            8:"file0008.txt",
            9:"file0009.txt"}

# change keys to searchable simple keyword phrases. 
concepts = {'GAMES':[1,2,4,3,3],
            'BLACKJACK':[5,3,5,3,5],
            'MACHINE':[4,9,9,9,4],
            'DATABASE':[5,3,3,3,5],
            'LEARNING':[4,9,4,9,4]}

# iterate through all var(words) found in var(word)
for word in words:
# convert to uppercase, search var(word) in dict 'concepts', if not found return not found"
    if word.upper() not in concepts:
        print("'{}':Not Found in Database \n" .format(word)) not in concepts
    else:
# for matching keys in dict 'concept' list values in dict 'files'
        for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
            print(files[pattern])

# return input box at end of query        
while True:
     concept(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
```

Comment: What do you mean by running in browser? You could use IPython, but there is a server in the background (on your PC though).

Comment: "So if the internet isn't available the file will still run in the browser." Browsers don't come with Python interpreters...

Comment: Do you usually run your Python programs on a website (like [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) for instance?) If so, and in case you are not aware, you can install [Python](https://www.python.org/) on your PC. But without additional libraries it won't run in a web browser ([IPython](https://ipython.org/) is such a library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install JupyterLab and run python project in a web browser by `http://localhost:8889/lab`

Easier way:

I installed [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) navigator which includes the JupyterLab and other convenient features such as python version control and packages control.